# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 12.10!

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth

Recently I have installed ubuntu 12.10. It shows my bluetooth device & bluetooth icon. But I could not pair or send or receive any files using obex push. How could I resolve this? This is a big problem to me.

```
terminal output of lsusb:

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
```

The output of `rfkill list all`:

> ```
> 0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> 1: hci0: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> ```

Comment: please, post the output of `rfkill list all`

Comment: output:


0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Tried this myself. I could establish connection with the phone and partially remote-control the laptop, but could not 'Send files' or 'Browse' as well. `I could not pair`
Does this mean you could not connect with the phone?
Also after enabling Bluetooth in BIOS I have 'bluetooth' kernel module loaded: `lsmod | grep bluetooth` and when I turn it on in System Settings an additional entry in `rfkill list` appears. What about you? Do you have any Bluetooth-related modules loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, 
 But then figured it out that the network adapter was switched off with the explicit function key provided by the laptop manufacturer when I was using windows. The blue tooth in Ubuntu started working after it was enabled in the windows boot

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with 12.10. Under 12.04 "rfkill list all" displays the following for bluetooth:

2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

I have a dell M1210 running 12.04. I am able to pair and maintain bluetooth connection with my BT mouse. BT mouse connection works after resuming from suspend as well. When I installed 12.10 rfkill does not list "dell-bluetooth..." -- only "hci0: Bluetooth" is listed. Also in 12.10 bluetooth connection to my mouse must be repaired after resuming from suspend. I tested "rfkill block bluetooth" and noticed the bluetooth indicator light does not go off under 12:10 (it did under 12.04). I reinstalled 12.04 and bluetooth works perfectly.

Hope this helps troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 'Blueman blutooth manager' from Ubuntu Software Center and restart computer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure "Blueman bluetooth manager" helps.

In my case, I tested with and without it. It seems random. Sometimes the bluetooth device will be found and will be working fine. Other times it won't even show up on `hcitool dev`, but it will be there on `lsusb` and it will be listed with all items as 'no' on `rfkill list all`.

When it does not work, I just restart the machine until eventually it works.